# Find the NullSpace of a matrix whose determinant is "almost" zero

Tags: matrix, numerics, linear-algebra

If $A$ is a matrix such that $\det(A)=0$, it is easy to get a basis of the kernel of $A$ with `NullSpace[A]`.

Now let's consider a matrix $B$, function of a parameter `p`. Suppose there exists a $p_0$ such that $\det(B(p_0))=0$ but that in Mathematica, the `p0` can only be estimated *numerically* and I get `Det[B[p0]]` equals to something small such as $10^{-10}$. Mathematically, `B[p0]` is invertible... and so `NullSpace[B[p0]]` yields the empty set.

**Question:** How could I find the kernel of $B(p_0)$?

Comment: Use the `Tolerance` option of `NullSpace`.

Comment: @DanielLichtblau TY for you efficient answer. I integrated it in the answer and then accepted it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The magical words are [Singular Value Decomposition.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singular_value_decomposition) The singular vectors corresponding to small singular values form the kernel. Of course, Singular Value Decomposition is available in Mathematica as `SingularValueDecomposition[]`. As confirmed by Daniel Lichtblau, the built-in `Tolerance` option to `NullSpace[]` does it this exact way.

Comment: @anderstood I am sure that is what Mathematica is doing with the `Tolerance` option.

Comment: Correct. `NullSpace` uses SVD under the hood.